# Proper approach to change a class functionality for unit testing?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm working on an old and large C++ codebase and I've been in the process of creating unit tests for components that have been missing them.

What's the proper way to mocking the functionality of these classes for testing purposes?  Currently I'm using virtual functions, and in my test module, I'm deriving a mock class from the base "production" class, and overriding functionality as needed.

Here's an example:

Production.cpp

```
class Production {
protected:
    int Servers = 0;
public:

    virtual bool IsValInRegistry(const std::string& regVal);
};

bool Production::IsValInRegistry(const std::string& regVal)
{
    HRESULT hr = GOOD;
    hr = WinSysCallToRegistry(regVal);

    if (HR)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Mock.cpp

```
class Mock : public Production {
public:
    bool IsValInRegistry(const std::string& regVal) override final;
};

Mock::IsValInRegistry(const std::string& regVal)
{
    return true;
}
```

Is this a proper way forward?  I'm concerned if I introduce too many `virtual` functions, I may see a performance hit which I would like to avoid.  If this `virutal` model is not ideal, what's a good method?

Comment: I've only done Java, but do you know how Dependency Injection works?

Comment: With an old, large existing legacy code base, refactoring the code to use Dependency Injection is itself a lot of effort.

Comment: The only "proper" way is the one that works correctly, that's the bottom line. Whether it's virtual functions; or, redefining some related classes so that the test class thinks it's using the real classes, but is instead using ones that return simulated data; or intentional and controlled violation of the One Definition Rule, for testing purposes; or preprocessor tricks -- everything is fair game. Whatever gets the job done. I've used all of these approaches, and then some, at various times.

Comment: You could use `#define MOCK_VIRTUAL final`.  Then when mocking it is non-final; when not mocking it is final hence devirtualized.  RTTI remains, to reduce chance of different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without any performance impact, you might want to try compile-time mocking like this:

```
class Production {
protected:
    int Servers = 0;
public:

    bool IsValInRegistry(const std::string& regVal);
};

bool Production::IsValInRegistry(const std::string& regVal)
{
#ifdef USE_MOCK_PRODUCTION
    return true;
#else
    HRESULT hr = GOOD;
    hr = WinSysCallToRegistry(regVal);

    if (HR)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
#endif
}
```

This would require recompilation with needed flags for the tests you need, but the production build will stay the same as it was. So it's just the matter of time that you can spend on running those unit-tests.

Comment: But that is like the absolute last choice. You want your production code to be your production code, nothing else.